# How can i make a loop that prints all other entries in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

So i need a program that will take an item in a list and print every other item in that list except for the initial item.

For example if i had a list such as:

```
ls = ['Sun','Earth','Mars','Venus']
```

When 'Sun' is selected then 'Earth', 'Mars' and 'Venus' would be printed, then the program would move onto 'Earth' printing 'Sun', 'Mars' etc etc...

I thought that this could be done with a for loop but i cant work out a way to make it work.

edit: Forgot to add what ive tried, here it is:

```
bodies = ['Sun','Earth','Mars','Venus']

for i in (bodies):
    bodies.remove(i)
    for j in bodies:
        print(j)
    print('\n')
    bodies.append(i)

print(bodies)
```

Does anyone have any input?

Comment: You are right, this can be done with a for-loop. Give that a go and post what you find if you're still stuck.

Comment: btw The code you have posted suffers from the well known problem of modifying a collection that you are iterating over.

Answer (score 1):

you may use:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(ls):
    print(*[e for j, e in enumerate(ls) if i != j])
```

output:

```
Earth Mars Venus
Sun Mars Venus
Sun Earth Venus
Sun Earth Mars
```

Answer (score 1):

So i listened to quamrana who posted a comment saying that it's a bad thing to edit a collection that I'm iterating over so I used a combination of for loops plus a bit of the answer from exe and came up with this:

```
ls = ['Sun','Earth','Mars','Venus']

for planet in ls:

    print('Current: ' + repr(planet))

    for i in ls:
        if i not in planet:
            print(i)

    print('\n')
```

Thank you to both exe and quamrana for helping me here.

Answer (score 0):

i think is just like

```
ls = ['sun','earth','mars','venus'];
a = 'earth';
for i in range (len(ls)):
    if ls[i] != a:
        print(ls[i]);
```

where a is the planet you dont want to show, 'cause i cant remember how to input values in python lol.

the len() function returns the length of an array, is very useful, i hope it'll helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
# these work if no duplicates in list
for item in lst:
    print(set(lst) - set([item])

for item in lst:
    print([I for I in lst if I != item])

# this works if potential duplicates
for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
    if idx == 0:
        print(lst[1:])
    elif idx == len(lst) - 1:
        print(lst[:-1])
    else:
        print(lst[0:idx] + lst[idx + 1:])
```